# Is evolution true as Darwin said?

Tags: evolution

I was telling the theory of evolution to my friends. But they asked me for the proof. They said, we are not seeing any such transition species at present. Neither we have such evidence for evolution. What should I do? I saw many proofs like archaeoptaryx, but now it has been proved that it is fully functional bird and others are also not supporting the theory of evolution given by Darwin!

Comment: You may want to look at the excellent series of links reported here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution

Comment: There is no proving something outside mathematics, there is however the scientific process in which we determine the way reality likely is, in many cases to near certainty. You will not necessarily become convinced by one post here. You will have to learn trust in the scientific community, or learn about enough evidence for evolution yourself to convince you its a sound theory. Two points: there is no alternative to evolution that explains the data, or makes predictions as well as the theory of evolution, and the failing of one point of evidence is not necessarily evidence the theory is wrong.

Comment: It may be true that you're seeking scientific evidence but your friends are looking for the black and white answer. If they are, you can preface repeating some of the excellent responses below with a bit of what a scientific theory is. When someone asks me for proof of something I usually can't give them that, I can only give them evidence.

Comment: @ktamlyn Ok, seems logical. Mind the word 'seems'. See, even the atomic model that you studied in high school was based on certain observations. But they were all rejected when a more sound model comes up. For instance, Bohr's atomic model was rejected by Schrodinger, which itself was rejected because of just one fault in it, and the world got Quantization model. And even there were some faults in it and therefore, 2nd quantization model comes up and so on. And that is the whole story. The scientific world is always changing! You can't say illogically that Darwin is right.

Comment: You have to have prove if something is right. And just having some evidences doesn't make something true! As I mentioned earlier, even there were evidences that supported Bohr's model, but its no more acceptable.

Comment: As far as faith is concerned, I have in everything logical and scientific. But now on things given by scientists which have no solid basis! If I believe it today, can you take the responsibility that in this changing scientific world, this theory will remain unchanged? You will say yes only if you are not in depth with the science. I am also a science student. But its not bad to accept its limitations, which makes it changing.

Comment: @Smith, I am unsure I understand your response completely. You state "You have to have prove if something is right". No we don't, we "demonstrate that something is very very likely true". Black and white terms like "throwing out" an old model, when there is only "one fault in it" is a false characterization of what happens in science. What happens is augmentation, and modification. This false perspective on science is what leads to a sense we should throw out the entire theory of evolution because one detail is not understood. Minds that think this way cannot practice science.

Comment: I should add that augmentation and modification is generally common, not the rule. The examples you provided in my opinion are modification and augmentation.

Answer (score 9):

I saw an excellent public science talk a few weeks ago. The speaker presented 5 questions which, if you answer yes to, you can only come to the conclusion that evolution exists. Firstly though we should define evolution: Evolution is the change in the inherited characteristics of biological populations over successive generations.

It was one of the best arguments I've seen put forward so I'll try to recreate it here. Put this to them and see what they say - and just in case they say no to any, I've put answers in for you ;) There is no hard evidence for the first four points because they are so damn obvious that if people say no, even after a logic based argument, then all they will ever say is no, they shouldn't need a scientific paper.

***1) Do individuals reproduce?***

The answer to this is undeniably yes, you were the result of reproduction. Reproduction exists.

***2) Is there variation among individuals?***

Yes, again this is undeniable. Do we all look and act the same? No. Are some people taller than others? Yes. Some more physically fit than others? Yes. Is everyone's hair or eye color the same? No. See, undeniable. Variation exists.

***3) Do some individuals die before they get to reproduce?***

Obviously yes. Children unfortunately die (of natural causes) which means they do no get to reproduce. Just go look in a cemetery or open the obituaries page of you newspaper and you'll likely find some one who died before they could have reproduced. Some people also never reproduce, because of life choices or fertility problems. Variance in reproductive success exists.

***4) Do offspring resemble parents?***

The answer to this is also yes, when two humans reproduce they (normally) produce something that resembles a human. And when that human reaches maturity they will likely look a more like their parents than a random stranger. Personally I was looking at old family photos recently and I honestly though I had found a picture of me marrying my mother, that's how similar my dad and I look. Heritability of variance exists.

***5) Does heritable variation lead to differences in reproductive success?***

If you've answered yes to all of the above then you really should be answering yes to this one too. As a hypothetical illustrative scenario, imagine two male deer. One has big antlers and one has small antlers. The size of antlers is largely genetically determined. The male with big antlers is seen as more attractive by a female. She chooses to mate with him. She gives birth to his offspring (n=2, 1 male 1 female) who inherit his genes for large antlers. This repeats with several females in the population (n=10). The smaller male has fewer mating events (n=2) and therefore sires fewer males in the next generation. The next generation contains more males with large antlers (n=10) than small antlers (n=2). This is evolution, the change in the inherited characteristics of biological populations over successive generations.

Another example is humans. We know [some men have low sperm counts leading to low probability of successful mating](http://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-topics/mens-sexual-health/male-infertility-22754.htm). Further, we know that [male infertility can be genetically](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20103481) caused for example by Y-linked genetic defects. Therefore we can expect that males with low sperm counts, caused by Y-linked defects, will have fewer offspring than a healthy male (given equal opportunity to mate) and because all males inherit their fathers Y chromosome they too will have low sperm counts. They will be represented at a lower level in the population's next generation. Again, this is evolution.

**Speciation:**

It then doesn't take much to jump from this to speciation. It involves the introduction of isolating mechanisms. These can be things like geography (allopatric speciation), or sympatric mechanisms like morphology, behavior, or any trait which prevents one group of individuals mating with another.

I'll illustrate first, and take the more difficult type - sympatric speciation. Again imagine our deer population. This time there is variance in sperm morphology, and female reproductive tracts. Males can produce two different types of sperm, one (male type S) is a slow moving but more resistant to the hostile female reproductive tract (because it is resistant to all types of antibody the females can produce), the other is faster (male type F) but less resistant (because it is resistant to only some of antibody the females can produce). Female reproductive tracts vary in the number of different antibodies they produce, one produces "all" that can be produced (female type R) and the other only a subset of the full array (female type W).

What will happen is that type S males will be more successful when mating with type R females because their sperm survive (whereas type F males have no sperm fertilizing the egg). However, type F males will be more successful in sperm competition than type S when mating to type W females. Repeated over many generations, these incompatibilities will cause distinct mating groups which do not overlap, i.e. species.

In reality it is much simpler to demonstrate this with allopatric speciation. Here two groups of one species become isolated by a geographical feature, like a river. Over time these populations evolve differently (because genetic mutation is random and selection might differ on opposite sides of the river). When they get the opportunity to mate after X generations, they can't because they have evolved genetic incompatibilities (offspring fail to survive, eggs can't bee fertilized).

One of the absolute classic examples is an experiment using fruit flies by Diane Dodd.   In her experiment she reared a population in two groups, one on starch based food, and one on maltose based food. After many generations (35 I think) the two groups showed mating preference, which is a reproductive isolating barrier, within their groups (mating pairs were more often formed from within treatments). [Here is the paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2409365).

[image]

Picture from http://evolution.berkeley.edu/

Comment: but still it doesn't prove evolution. When I say evolution, I mean formation of completely different species. In biology, two species are considered different if they can't produce a young one without mating. You are just proving that variations are inherited. I agree. But you didn't explain how this variation can lead to two different species. And this is exactly why I asked this question because I am facing a lot of similar questions.

Comment: @Smith That's speciation, not evoltuion. I'll add something in shortly, but you should be able to see how this extends to speciation.

Comment: Ok. But we have read that this evolution lead to speciation. And that what I want to know, how?

Comment: @Smith does this explain it for you?

Comment: @Smith. Speciation isn't so cut and dry as being able to mate. Reproductive isolation can exist in many forms. What about two animals that are able to reproduce and have viable offspring, but their reproductive organs have incompatible morphology so fertilization never naturally occurs? This would be a physical barrier to reproduction. Diane Dodd's fly experiment is similar, except that the animals have behavioural barriers.

You accept that variation can happen. What makes you not accept that variation can lead to speciation? What kind of forces would prevent it?

Comment: Going from variation to speciation is not that easy as you told. Why? Because different species have different morphology and anatomy. Variations only result in slight change of them. You can't expect a complete different species with variation. For an instance, human from monkey. But if humans evolved from monkeys, why we no more see any of the intermediate species? Even in the example of bee above, you will still get two closely related species. If you have any doubt, you can check with a DNA engineer, who can shower more light on it on the basis of more scientific DNA study.

Comment: @Smith Speciation isn't black and white, it is a gradual process.  To say we don't see intermediates between humans and apes is kind of wrong, some apes are closer to humans than others, humans 10000 years ago were more ape like than current humans and in 10000 years humans will be even less ape like, we are still diverging. Evolution and speciation do not stop, speciation is when we diverge enough to be considered separate species, but we will continue to evolve away from apes

Comment: @GriffinEvo I think you need to check the fossil records again in more depth which are contradictory to what you said! The human fossils found that are thousands to millions of years old, resemble the same shape. Caution: Dont depend on textbooks you are given. I faced a lot of criticism because of that. Search on internet the records. You would love to see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bolcLN6_JWc).

Comment: @smith As some one with a degree and a masters in evolution and two years in to a phd on evolution, I think I'm in a good enough position to judge what material to trust for myself but thanks for the great advice. Clearly you don't want to have your question answered by anything other than the answer you want. If you want an argument about the evidence of evolution go to a forum, this place is for questions and answers.

Comment: I also happen to work in one of the best departments in the world for the study of human evolution, I'd rather go to them for lessons on human evolution, not some guy on a website and a YouTube video. Science is peer reviewed, YouTube isn't, evidence that goes against the norm is welcomed by the scientific community, but the guy in the video is presenting weak subjective evidence against strong objective evidence.

Comment: @smith http://www.nhm.ac.uk/nature-online/evolution/what-is-the-evidence/morphology/hominid-skulls/

Comment: @GriffinEvo I know these, I am not a non-evolutionist. But there are evidences of human fossils millions of years old. Thats what I have to say.

Comment: @smith that says nothing, yes there are human fossils, but what is that supposedly telling us which goes against what Darwin or the theory if evolution says?

Comment: @GriffinEvo and thats why I am sure that Darwin was wrong. Have you read his book The origin of Species? Highly unscientific, although logical. He is assuming a hell lot of things on his own. ID is better option.

Comment: @smith so quote me what he said, why your evidence goes against what Darwin or (more importantly) the theory of evolution say, and how does it better suit ID?

Answer (score 4):

The best proof of evolution is not in the fossil record, but perhaps in the living things you see around us right now.

For instance the rise of antibiotic resistant bacteria is the direct result of selection. The environment for the bacteria changed - we introduced antibiotics.  The vast majority of the bacteria die, but eventually the survivors are resistant- just in the space of a few years.

Adaptation and even speciation is occurring around us and can be observed directly.

A case that all of has seen, and was one of the most important to Darwin's argument in the Origin of Species is how we breed domestic animals.  By selecting animals with characteristics they find desirable, all sorts of animals are created by the use of selection - breeding the animals you want and then not breeding animals with characteristics that are not desirable.  Cats, dogs, horses, sheep - using selection any animal you want can be modified [nearly to the point you can't recognize it](http://www.sonoma-marinfair.org/ugly-dog-gallery).  This is a multibillion dollar industry when you think of all the livestock and pet breeders in the world.

The most famous scientific experiment along this lines is [Dmitry Belyaev's domesticated fox experiment](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/early-canid-domestication-the-farm-fox-experiment/1) where over 40 years the foxes who were the friendliest to humans and bred them together.  As a control experiment the most hostile foxes were also bred together.  The result is an animal which is as friendly as a golden retriever, even though no fox had ever before been taken as a pet.

There are dozens of other stories.  Selection for breeding plants is another such success story.  Though it takes more work and time, Selection is as reliable as electronics as a technology.

Making someone believe something that they don't want to is much harder though.

Comment: ok. May be you are right. But still, this may be valid for asexual reproduction. What about sexual reproduction case. Is there an example in that too?

Comment: added another case above

Answer (score 4):

Despite evolution is generally macroscopically appreciable after a long time, there are some examples observable right now.

- A classic example is the [evolution of the **peppered moth**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppered_moth_evolution) (Biston betularia) in the last two hundred years. Originally the predominant color was white, which camouflaged them against light-coloured trees such as *Betula* plants, while dark-colored moths were rare. During the Industrial Revolution in England the pollution blackened many trees, causing most of the light-coloured moths to die off from predators. The black-coloured ones (called *carbonaria*) flourished because of their ability to hide on the darkened trees.
- The best example about whole species evolving is the **ring species**. Here is a good definition from wikipedia:

  > In biology, a ring species is a connected series of neighbouring populations, each of which can interbreed with closely sited related populations, but for which there exist at least two "end" populations in the series, which are too distantly related to interbreed, though there is a potential gene flow between each "linked" species. Such non-breeding, though genetically connected, "end" populations may co-exist in the same region thus closing a "ring".
  >
  > Ring species provide important evidence of evolution in that they illustrate what happens over time as populations genetically diverge, and are special because they represent in living populations what normally happens over time between long deceased ancestor populations and living populations, in which the intermediates have become extinct. Richard Dawkins observes that ring species "are only showing us in the spatial dimension something that must always happen in the time dimension."

  You can continue the reading at the related [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species).

Comment: peppered moth just adapted to this change and their body colour changed. But are both different species?

Comment: No, they are not. It's an example of current evolution. You can look at the "ring species" example for the speciation (read the wikipedia article!).

Comment: I added a larger quotation from wikipedia, now is self-explanatory.

Comment: The ring species is an excellent example of evolution of species.  The two endpoint populations are essentially different species, and you can find the gradations between them in the ring around the globe.  Remove the intermediate populations and all you have are two (related) species.

Comment: @mgkrebbs - Great comment about ring species.  Here's a nice explanation: http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/evolution/library/05/2/l_052_05.html

Comment: But lets become somewhat practical. If you read from that wiki page only, it says only four species are found to follow this concept of ring species. So, again, if this is the right concept, atleast majority of species are supposed to follow it. And thus, this idea still is just a concept and not a law, which is universally applicable. Any comments?

Comment: Ring species is a _special_ case in which the intermediates haven't become extinct. The general trend is the contrary. The theory of evolution will be forever a theory: you can't pretend to _see_ the evolution of every single specie in the planet. However, like Stephen Jay Gould [said](http://www.stephenjaygould.org/library/gould_fact-and-theory.html), it is "confirmed to such a degree that it would be perverse to withhold provisional assent." Sure the ring species concept alone can't prove evolution.

Comment: so, in the end it comes to faith only! We have to just accept. Then what is the problem in Intelligent Design? Even you have to put faith there! But that is more scientific than saying that everything we see around evolved by chance. I have never seen any discovery taking place by chance. A scientist may be working on something and not getting results. But he may get that by chance. But to believe that anything just came up by change is illogical and unscientific! In ID, atleast they tell its a design by a designer which is more logical than saying chemicals combine on their own and life came!

Comment: You have several misconceptions about the theory of evolution, however you wouldn't have written certain things. I can't explain you all because I'm italian and not a good english speaker and because you will need a _long_ answer. Moreover, your question was about present transition species. I suggest you to read a popular-scientific book about evolution. You can ask a new question for suggestions about it!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you dont see a transition species at present! A transitions species is what existed between two other species. When it "becomes" the new species, the transition species no longer exists. Transition species only exist in the past. Its also important to remember that species are a spectrum. When we divide things up into discreet species it makes it seem all neat and tidy but really it is not because of the large amount of variation that exists within a species. When the variation becomes so great that certain members of the species may not be able to interbreed, we break it into two species.

I also do not see why you need to visually see evolution to believe it exists. The strongest evidence can be found in DNA or protein sequences. Look at any conserved protein and see the similarities. I will give you a link that shows the difference between the mouse and human version of a protein called p53. p53 is studied a lot because it is thought to have a role in cancer. Im not even sure if p53 is considered a "highly conserved" gene, but look at how similar it is!

[ps53 protein alignment](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web/toolresult.ebi?jobId=clustalw2-I20131001-161406-0148-38128470-oy)*

How many generations difference do you think there is between a mouse and human? [remeber humans did not evolve from mice, they just had a common ancestor, so what I mean is how many generations have elapsed since the last common ancestor]? [It is estimated that mice / humans disverged some 70 million years ago.](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/172/5/2731.full) Lets say a generation (age difference between parent and child) is ~30 years in humans (it is much much much much less in mice but lets forget about that) that means there were some ~2 million generations, and thats being conservative. [This website](http://massgenomics.org/2012/08/de-novo-mutations-and-human-disease.html) claims there are 74 de novo[new] mutations in humans each generation. Technically this is not all mutations but again we are being conservative. So that is about a 150 million mutation difference between humans and the ancestor that became both humans and mice

My question to you is this: Look again at the similarities between human and mouse p53. You see how there are some differences? Dont you think it is entirely possible that the differences can be accounted for after having 150,000,000 chance mutations?**

Now imagine this happening to every gene, not just p53. That is evolution

*Not sure how long this link will be valid but you can see the sequences at these links and do the alignment yourself [here](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalw2/)

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/200203?report=fasta

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/23491729?report=fasta

**Actually double that to account for mouse evolving from the common ancestor but like I said, wanted to be conservative

Answer (score -4):

There are six different types of evolution and they all happen on different levels.

1. Cosmic evolution- the origin of time, space and matter. Big Bang
2. Chemical evolution- the origin of higher elements from hydrogen.
3. Stellar and planetary evolution- Origin of stars and planets.
4. Organic evolution- Origin of life from inanimate matter.
5. Macro-evolution- Origin of major kinds.
6. Micro-evolution- Variations within kinds. Only this one has been observed. For instance poodles and great danes are descendant from the same thing. A wolf.

Are you asking about macro evolution or micro evolution? Or one of the other 4?

Speciation does not show macro evolution in any way, shape, or form. And the ring species you refer to moths changing colors, that is micro evolution. A moth changing into another moth would even be micro evolution.

Man thought up species and defined them. If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it didn't evolve into a different animal because it changed the color of it's feathers.

Comment: You're using some rather strange terminology, your first 4 points are generally not called evolution, the Big Bang and abiogenesis are not part of the theory of evolution. And the division into macro- and microevolution is misleading, it is exactly the same process.

Comment: It is not the same process and they are all forms of evolution. Define macro and define micro and let's see if they are the same. Micro are finite changes that can happen independently of macro evolution. Are you saying you can't have micro, without macro? Or are you saying you can't have macro, without micro? If you can have micro without macro then they are different.